# Is MatLab worth buying?

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, computer-science

I can access MatLab on school computers, but it would be more like a convenience factor as of right now. I want to get into programming using raspberry pi later on, but is it worth buying in the meantime? Will it be useful to me as a computer engineer? Thanks.

Comment: My opinion is "No", but it depends a lot on why you want to use it. There are some fields where it is very popular. If you lean toward the electrical engineering side, it could be valuable.

Comment: Matlab is useful but this question unfortunately is not a good fit for Stackoverflow

Comment: Have you tried Octave?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have used Matlab as a student and employee for over 10 years now.  I have recently taken an interest in Python as a free open-source alternative to Matlab and have been extremely impressed.  Matlab is a very powerful and convenient tool, but has a significant cost, especially if toolboxes are needed.  Python seems to cover all the same capability needs that I have in Matlab (with toolboxes), and if I ever need help doing something in python that I know how to do in matlab, I just do a quick google search and 9 times out of 10 I end up on this website, taking advantage of the questions that others have already answered.

With your question on Raspberry pi, it can actually run python code on board, but not the case for matlab.

I am not a computer engineer, but am of the opinion that python would likely benefit you more than matlab in the end as it is free, more widely used and can be used on devices such as raspberry pi.  For reference, I have degrees in physics and electrical engineering and spend a great deal of time at work building optical sensors, operating them, and processing their data.

One more note: I like the Anaconda distribution of python, highly recommended

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks! I will definitely look into python for this instead.

Comment: If in addition to Python you still find useful having Matlab available from time to time, check if your school has a student pricing for Matlab. In my university it is about 25$ a year, which is quite affordable.

Comment: I've used Matlab for years, and just recently started learning Python (100% free) and R (100% free).  I think both are worth a look, and both seem to be much more popular than Matlab.  Look at the number of questions posted here on SO.
Python ~ 499,000
R ~ 115,000
Matlab ~ 54,500

Also, do a quick Google search, and see what the top 10 languages are...
http://spectrum.ieee.org/computing/software/the-2015-top-ten-programming-languages

Matlab comes in dead last.  I like Matlab, and I'll continue to use it, but at the same time, I'll keep an open mind about alternative technologies.